# syslog-ng keep source hostname and last relay

Tags: syslog-ng

I have SSB and syslog-ng clients writing to it. I need to have in logs hostname of source of log (using `keep_hostname(yes)`) and IP of last relay, like with option `keep_hostname(no)` in log. I need both of them in the same log, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable trusted option on Log/Source (keep_hostnames(yes)), and then you can create a rewrite rule one on Log/Paths page with a custom name (e.g. ip) as message part, and ${SOURCEIP} as replacement value. This way the SSB will put the source IP to a macro named ip, which will appear on the search page as a dynamic column.